# Easiest way to have "yyyy.mm.dd" format in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

So I realized that this isn't a common date type to deal with at least with using `as.Date()`. When I do the following , the output isn't correct.

```
> as.Date(Sys.Date(), format = "yyyy.mm.dd")
[1] "2022-06-21"
```

Is there an easy way to this with lubridate or base R?

Comment: `format(Sys.Date(), '%Y.%m.%d')`

Comment: You can either have the date as an actual date, in which case it will display in the format "2022-06-21", _or_ you can have a character string representing the date in any format you like. Once you format a date, it turns into a character string and you can no longer carry out various date-time operations on it. You should work with dates in the standard format, and only change their format once ready to plot or otherwise present your data.

Comment: @akrun, please post as answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `format` instead of `as.Date` as `Sys.Date()` is already in `Date` class, however as commented, `format` returns only a `character` class

```
format(Sys.Date(), '%Y.%m.%d')
```